# Linux server filesystem issues

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems, openvz

I have a vps with file system trouble and the provider has been unable to fix it.

If `/dev/simfs` is missing on a clean install (CentOS 5.5), and not created later, will this cause serious problems with a file system using (Root filesystem) SIMFS 
Location = `/dev/simfs` ??

The obvious answer (to me) would be YES, this is a serious problem.

I have 3 VPS's: The two "good" ones use `/` (Root filesystem) Reiser Filesystem (reiserfs) by default and the Location = `/dev/simfs`

The location `/dev/simfs` DOES show an empty file (container / whatever), and the systems work great.

The "bad" VPS shows / (Root filesystem) SIMFS and the Location = `/dev/simfs`.

The location `/dev/simfs` does NOT show anything there.

The provider claimed to have "fixed" the config file on my container, but it is still giving out a nightmare of file errors, SSH blocks all connections, etc.

After reboot everything is OK for ~30 minutes, and then it all Melts-Down again.

> > > If '/dev/simfs' is missing (CentOS 5.5) will this cause serious problems with a file system using (Root filesystem) SIMFS Location = /dev/simfs ??

How can I teach my provider to fix this?

Comment: added openvz tag, SIMFS is a container construct of this platform. for a nifty explanation: http://wiki.openvz.org/OpenVZ_disk_quota,_df_and_stat_weird_behaviour

Comment: if you need to teach your provider anything, then get another one!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong whatever the fstab or the mtab contains.

So `/dev/simfs` and different variations means nothing wrong. If the host itself has filesystem or I/O problems the guest (your vps) will suffer, but this is not related to what you see in the `mount` command output.

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely to be unfixable. Do a new setup and restore from backup.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure things are apples to apples, are all containers on the same hardware node? If not, you'll be spinning in circles trying to troubleshoot.

My experience has been that OpenVZ and Virtuozzo are bad news. I would switch to Amazon's EC2 or something at Linode or Rackspace running on Xen.

OpenVZ is OK if you're trying to put things into containers and run the hardware but it's very easy to over sell with this technology so companies like to cram >30 customers with 512M of memory per machine on a hardware node with just 4G of memory.  The math doesn't add up.

I've worked for and have started several hosting companies and I would advise getting off of OpenVZ. The pricing for Xen based hosting has come down and you'll have a better experience so you can worry about the business and not the infrastructure.